# Windows power plans and performance + virtual machines?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I don't know if it makes a difference, mostly want to know if its a bad idea or could be atleast, before, If I ever do change it. I am using virtualbox.

High performance vs balanced. Any risk involved by possibly or over stressing your computer ect?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Whether power plan is better for a virtual machine, or which power plan works better for a host running virtual machines, or something else entirely? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes, in a general sense what is the effect if any that's relevant when high performance/low/??/ is on or off. Im guessing their is other performance acceleration options other than windows power plan setting but they are probably very similar in effects so Im assuming. In my particular case windows 10. Just advice I suppose if any.

Comment: Most of the settings in the power plan just relate to how aggressive Windows is at putting the computer to sleep/hibernate. In addition, there are a few settings that specify whether components can enter a low power state or not. For instance, on a laptop, Power Saver will throttle the CPU instead of turning up the fan. High Performance won't "over stress" anything, it just prevents low power states.

Comment: So you're asking what effects, if any power states of the host will have on VMs running on it? It's still not clear if you're asking about the host or the VMs.

Comment: I did not assume the effect would be over-stress, I simply recall reading something in that regard to a setup probably far from my own. I figured it wouldn't play a big role in anything (windows power plans). I paid attention to them more ever since my last hard drive failed. But again, I dont assume the power plan caused that at all. It just made me curious if the power plans payed any effect to the virtual machines separately from the windows OS. Other then a unique relation to VM's I have no questions about the power plans.  I am only learning about Virtual machines now.

Comment: Sorry if this is not making lots of sense, it was not a well thought out question.  On the fly! kinda deal.

Comment: It's a good question. Honestly, I hadn't put much thought into tuning the power management of my virtual machines either, and I run them on an enterprise level. At the server level you aren't really dealing with power management at the software level though. Based on your clarification though, I assume the first part of my answer is the applicable part, and basically: it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Pending clarification by OP:

**If you're asking whether certain power states on the VMs are better or worse:**

The answer is that it doesn't matter. The hypervisor provides all of the processing and only commands that it allows are sent to the host CPU and processed. I'd run any VMs in High Performance, personally, simply because it doesn't matter.

**If you're asking whether certain power states on the host are better or worse for the VMs:**

This is harder to answer, but still not a difficult question. In an enterprise environment this might be something worth considering, but on a home computer with a few VMs doing basic lab work in Virtual Box you're not going to cause actual problems running the system one way or another. The VMs could prevent the host from going to sleep as quickly, and the time it takes to pause the VMs will generally make any hibernate or shut down process take a bit longer unless you've shutdown or paused the VMs first. Also, the processor power management settings will affect the real speed of the processor, and this will obviously affect how "fast" the VMs run at the same time.

Unless you're running some high-end processing on your VMs you're not going to cause any real problems due to power management. And if you're running high-end processing on this setup, I'd seriously question why you consider a home computer and Virtual Box appropriate for that task.

Comment: By host I assume you mean the computer that is actually running the virtual  machine on it. I am not running high end processing setup, I just remember reading something regarding this and wanted to ask myself as I found it hard to believe. I cannot remember the specifics at all and im far from hardcrore anything, I am completely new to virtual machines and if not then close. Thanks for your answer sorry about the need for clarity.

Comment: Eh, no worries. You don't know the words surrounding virtualization, so just do your best. You might find you have to use several words where those more familiar with it will use one or two, but then you'll get more familiar with the topic and more comfortable with the lingo.

Comment: Yes, "host", "hypervisor", and "physical machine" in the context of virtualization all refer to the computer and operating system that are actually running "on metal" on the physical computer, inside which the virtual machines are running.